# Bottom line on Iphone 10, 11

Tags: react-native

I am novice to React Native. Help, does anyone know how to change the color of the bottom white line on an Iphone 10 and beyond?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggSTf.jpg

Comment: Looks like that's related to ```SafeAreaView```, can you show some code? Because if so, then you can set your custom background color in style prop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.